# How to copy a channel ID that a user sent

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want the bot to get the channel ID sent by a user in the channel where the interaction was made. I want the bot to copy the channel ID and store it in my mongoose database.

#### For example:

The bot requests the channel ID, I respond with the channel ID "123456789", the bot copies it and sends it back in the form of an embed with the channel mention, and saves it in the database.

#### Code:

```js
try {
    // Defer the initial reply
    await interaction.deferReply();
    // Send the initial message with the embed
    await interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [
            new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({
                name: interaction.user.username,
                iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL(),
            })
            .setColor(Color)
            .addFields({
                name: "Provide a Channel ID",
                value: "Please provide the channel ID where you wish the **Reviews** to be displayed.",
            }),
        ],
    });

    // Collect the user's response
    const filter = (message) => message.author.id === interaction.user.id;
    const collected = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
        filter,
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ["time"],
    });

    const message = collected.first();
    const channelID = message.content.trim();

    // Send the follow-up message with the provided channel ID
    await interaction.followUp(
        `You provided the following channel ID: ${channelID}`
    );
} catch (error) {
    // Handle if an error occurs or no response is received within the given time
    interaction.followUp("You did not provide a channel ID. Configuration canceled.");
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Give more details.

Comment: It just says "You did not provide a channel ID. Configuration canceled." just after I press the button.

Comment: Console.log the error in the catch statement and tell me what it says